# php error array to string conversion when using variable

Tags: php, oracle

when I want to exetuce this, I got error :

> Notice: Array to string conversion because of company.username =
>   '$user'

If I will change $user with the name of user, the code work fine, what is the problem with this `$user`. BTW. `$user`, is loged user assigned to variable $user

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select users.no_user,  users.post_user from users
        inner join best_users on (best_users.no_user = users.no_user)
        where exists( select username from company where
            best_users.username = company.username and company.username = '$user')");
    oci_execute($stid);
    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))!= false){
        echo $row['no_user'] . " " . $row['post_user'] . "$<br>\n";
    }
```

Comment: `BTW. $user, is loged user assigned to variable $user` PHP seems to think otherwise.

Comment: what do you mean? when i'm logging in, the username that I user, is stored in $user

Comment: What does `var_dump($user);` output?

Comment: how to put var_dump in sql querry? I will try to explain again: when I log in to user ex: John1, and instead of $user, I will put John1, it will print user number and his post. I just wrote this querry in sql, I don't know how php should work. but if I user $user, that need to take John1 and assign it (but it's assign cause other part of code work) I have this error

Comment: Put the `var_dump($user);` right before the line where you create your sql query. So `var_dump($user);  $stid = oci_parse($conn, ...`

Comment: Oh ok ,This: array (size=2)
  'user_type' => string 'accountant' (length=10)
  'floor' => string '1' (length=1), cause before this code I have "if": if ($user['floor']!=4 && $user ['user_type'] != 'manager)

Comment: You're trying to concatenate a string with an array and php doesn't like it. `$user` should be  a string like `username_123` not an array.

Comment: well.. user is  John1, is a string, no?

Comment: Maybe you need to post more code so you can get more advice now that it's clear that `$user` is an array.